# Apply desired display language while starting a process

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

While my users' display language is English, I want to show some parts of windows in another installed language. I'm using `Process.Start("control", "desk.cpl")` to open up Display Settings, but I want it to be in Persian language. (Users have Persian language installed in their computer) How is that achievable?
I tried setting the thread's culture info but that didn't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you cannot set your own language to the particular window in the desktop.

More over, you cannot even set a language to **any** system process being started up. This follows from the necessity of **relogging** into a user account after you making a change to the UI language in the control panel.

Thus, you can have only **all** of your processes and windows to be in another language, and only after a relog, so your goal in unarchivable unless you write your own window in your WPF app.

### In that case:

You need to implement a localization logic in your application.

In case you are using the WPF, you might end up reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies) or [googling for another](https://www.google.ru/search?q=wpf+localization).

In short, you will have to define a table in resources which will contain all the phrases in its rows and their translations in its columns where your localization adapter along with some ViewModel magic (the [binding](https://www.google.ru/search?q=wpf+binding)) will make to your user interface easy-switchable and multi-lingual.

Comment: So I need to implement all my needed functionalities witch are already implemented in Windows myself?

Comment: Yes you do need. There is another way of doing it, but you won't like it... there it is: you massively use the windows API to find each control on the form of Display Settings, then you deeply gid into Windows's resources, finding that MUI localization you need (if it exists, and not encrypted, and you have access and rights to it), then you search thought it by using specified **keys** which you don't know, and **then** you switch that texts on the form. Again, using Windows API.